# Google Icons not linking... is it just HTML or CSS issue?

Tags: html, css

on my website http://www.derekbeck.com/1775/ I have social media button icons, and strangely, the Google icons don't link, though they have links encoded. I can't figure it out. There are two google buttons: the white one is for the +1 and that doesn't work, the red one is to take you to the google page. Neither works in Google Chrome browser, but the red one works in IE9. Any ideas? See any CSS or HTML errors?

Thanks for looking! Derek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook iFrame is your issue:

The Iframe was  height: 20px; width: 200px;

Change it to the code below

The Iframe was  height: 20px; width: 74px;

```
<iframe scrolling="no" id="f234707a0d2f204" name="f21e0c9e1942cf6" style="border: medium none; overflow: hidden; height: 20px; width: 74px;" title="Like this content on Facebook." class="fb_ltr" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?api_key=122700491127449&amp;channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D4%23cb%3Dfb3ad41882f634%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.derekbeck.com%252Fff890b510a65%26domain%3Dwww.derekbeck.com%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;extended_social_context=false&amp;font=tahoma&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F1775thebook&amp;layout=button_count&amp;locale=en_US&amp;node_type=link&amp;sdk=joey&amp;send=false&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=200"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks, so simple, I set it to width 85pixels though, to match the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

This div..

```
 <div id="connect_widget_4f8e67257c86d8966624510" class="connect_widget button_count"
       style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot;, sans-serif">..</div>
```

is 200px wide and appears over the top of the google div bounds. When you attempt to click on the +1 you are really clicking on an invisible area of the facebook div. In google chrome, right click the +1 button and click inspect element. This will allow you to see the boundaries of the div.

Answer (score 1):

In you facebook plugin code change the width to 85px from 200px.

There are no problems in your G+ button. The facebook button is overlapping it making it non-clickable.

@WhiteboardDev - Instead of setting width to a div which is generated by plugin, it would be advisable to change width of plugin itself.

Answer (score 1):

There's this div `<div id="connect_widget_4f8e8b1c2eea08763746363" class="connect_widget button_count" style="font-family: &quot;tahoma&quot;, sans-serif">` with a fixed width (200px), that "covers" the google buttons, but it has a transparent background, so you're not seeing it.

solution: give this div `<div class="fb-likebox">` width: 200px;. It's the iframe's container, so it will make the google buttons shift to the right, and let you click them.